# Pentaho Community Dashboard: one datasource for multiple charts controlled by hard-coded parameter

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to display three charts on a dashboard, with one MDX datasource behind them.
The difference in the three charts is a filter (a location of an outlet). 
I have made a parameter OUTLETNAME and put that in my MDX.
Then for each of the three charts, I created that parameter in the parameter dialog of the chart. 
I have not created the parameter as its own component.

I have set it to a string value in the component. That is, I in the chart component I have entered a parameter with arg OUTLETNAME and a value of 'AAA', 'BBB' and 'CCC' in the three chart components.

However, this doesn't work. The filter choose the ALL member.

If I define a generic simple parameter for each value of OUTLETNAME, like declaring a variable to hold a constant value, and use this as the value of the parameter in the chart, then it works. So I can't seem to assign a string value directly to

For example,  I make a generic -> simple parameter as a component and call it OUTLET_AAA and give it the property value AAA (not in quotes), and then on the relevant chart make a parameter with argument OUTLETNAME and value OUTLET_AAA, it works. But this seems cumbersome. I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following:

1. The parameter is properly entered into the query. If your parameter is OUTLETNAME, you must have something like ${OUTLETNAME} somewhere in your query.
2. Check that the parameter definition of each chart is correct: the first column of the parameter must match OUTLETNAME (case sensitive), and the value must match "AAA" or 'AAA' (with quotes!), etc.
3. If the behaviour is still the same, open your javascript console when rendering the dashboard and check what you get with

`render_<component_name>.parameters` and `render_<component_name>.queryState.lastResults().resultset`. See whether the resultsets are indeed equal or if they're different.

Comment: You suspicion was correct. When I enabled debug logs I saw that I was getting <null> in the MDX because I had change the parameter name on the chart associated with the query.